# Blotchy crispy tomato leaves

Tags: tomatoes

These are an heirloom variety (tomande), I have tried giving them less and more water with no difference.

I have 3 plants of this variety and they are all suffering the same problem.

It starts on the lower leaves with little spots that look a little see-through, the edges of the leaves start to curl and then turn brown until eventually the leaf turns crispy and brittle.

I am growing 3 other varieties all in the same area which do not suffer this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Tomato leaf with brown edges]

[image: Underside of leaf with brown edges]

[image: Shrivelled dry leaves]

![new4]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/middQ.jpg)
[image: new5]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the full plant, the last picture makes it seem like the plant is wilting pretty hard. If that is the case I would suspect it is due to breakage in the stems (if you are not using a cage for support) or too little water given the amount of sun it gets (although you say you tried increasing the water).

Comment: What kind of fertilizer, and how much and how often? What kind of water are you giving them? Did you use fresh seed-starting mix?

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx brings up a good point, if you are overfertilizing your plant then it will also show signs of underwatering (wilting) but increasing watering won't help unless you drench and drain the soil multiple times to clear out the excess fertilizer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. 

I have added 2 pictures which show more of the plant. 

I did try giving them more water to no avail, however I am not thinking that may be the problem, the pots seem to be getting lighter even though I am giving them the same amount of water, maybe they are using more, or more is evaporating. 

The only additional nutrients I have supplied so far is some phostrogen.

Comment: Compost was john innes no 2. The phostrogen was added a couple of weeks ago, solution made as per the instructions on the box

Comment: Sorry, previous comment should have said that I now think that may be the problem, in relation to underwatering.

Answer (score 1):

It is from edema.  Too much water.  It will just keep killing the plant, slowly one set of leaves at a time.  Notice the little bubbles and coloration of the stem…